# Worklight Database Integration

Tags: database, ibm-mobilefirst

1. In worklight.properties server config file, you may specify only 1 database type for Worklight Server to work with. But is there a scenario where it a Worklight app can handle connecting to multiple Databases? One example could be, core Worklight databases tables (WLREPORT, WRKLGHT) uses an Oracle DB. But some SQL adapters connect to a different Database like mysql through adapter configs
2. Does Worklight automatically reconnect to DB after a failure?
3. Is Worklight app compatible with Oracle ASM
4. Are core Worklight DBs (WLREPORT, WRKLGHT) capable of using DB partitions

Answer (score 1):

1. That would be a valid scenario. In worklight.properties you handle settings related for the Worklight Server mostly. Adapters are project-level, not worklight-server-level, you do not define nor handle them in worklight.properties - each SQL adapter is a separate entity you create within your project, and each SQL adapter has its own XML with connection settings, etc.
2. Are you referring to the client or server? but both should, yes. More exact scenarios are needed to fully answer.
3. When it comes to Oracle, Worklight [supports only Oracle 11g](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=C2E8EF801E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36). See full [System Requirements for IBM Worklight and IBM Mobile Foundation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838)
4. leaving empty for now. Will edit.

Comment: 4. Running Worklight 5.0.6

Answer (score 1):

4 . Yes, database partitions can be specified when you create the databases manually. You modify the manual setup instructions [Creating the Oracle databases](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_creating_the_oracle_databases.html) to take into account your desired partitioning.