# IBM Worklight , SQL Adapter(Oracle 10g), using jndi name for connectivity

Tags: oracle10g, jndi, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

**Adapter xml file, the connectio policy**
`<connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
<dataSourceJNDIName>${custom-db.1.jndi-name}</dataSourceJNDIName> 
</connectionPolicy>`

**wl.property file**

```
custom-db.1.jndi-name=${custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name}
custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name=jdbc/datasrc
custom-db.1.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
custom-db.1.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
custom-db.1.username=hr
custom-db.1.password=tiger
```

I have imported the jar files ojdbc14.jar

**The adapter is deployed but gives error at runtime as,**
    {
       "errors": [
          "Runtime: Datasource jdbc/datasrc not found in jndi"
       ],
       "info": [
       ],
       "isSuccessful": false,
       "warnings": [
       ]
    }

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Oracle 10g. I think Worklight does not support Oracle 10g. It only supports Oracle 11g. You can also refer this link- [Worklight Database Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158634/worklight-database-integration)